# How do I ignore Eclipse errors if I include junit.jar from somewhere else?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit, easymock

Basically, I created a `build.xml` for Apache Ant. I use all the `.jar` files such as `easymock.jar`, `junit.jar`, which I downloaded straight from the their websites for my library (set in `build.xml`).

When I created a new unit test file using those two above `.jar` files by:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Eclipse generated bunch of errors. However, when I ran `build.xml` as Ant, this didn't seem to be a problem (no compile errors). I guess Eclipse doesn't recognize the external libraries until it actually compiles. How do I ignore these errors for certain unit test files? Or more generally, make Eclipse recognize external libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in `Project properties->Java Build Path`. This has options to add jars to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting the jar files in the project does not guarantee that it is included in the Project Class path. You need to set it manually.

In Properties-->Java Build Path, add a User Library (for example) and include your jar files there.